# Django: Related Objects for Authenticated User

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In Django we can create related models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class TaskSet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tasksets')
    title = models.Charfield()

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tasks')
    taskset = models.ForeignKey(TaskSet, related_name='tasks')
```

Makes sense, I can call `request.user.tasksets`– but what's the correct way to get the tasks in the taskset? `request.user.tasksets.first().tasks` will return all of the tasks for the entire task set– but how can I get the tasks for that user only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `.filter()` on that. So the whole query would be `request.user.tasksets.first().tasks.filter(user=request.user)`. However, this is only useful if you want to get a task from the **first** task set of the user only and this structure would only be productive if the tasks defined inside each task set can belong to other users other than the task set owner.

If you just want to get a task belonging to that user regardless of whether it is in the first task set or not, you can do `request.user.tasks.first()`.

Comment: This generally works– something I didn't specify (but should have) is that I'm doing this from a DRF serializer: so I'm trying to do something like `tasks = TaskSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source='tasks')` <-- any way to do the equivalent from that source?

Comment: Yes, you can. Defining it exactly as you wrote it in this comment should return tasks belonging to that user only (regardless of which task sets they're in). However, if you want `tasks` in your serializer to have only the tasks belonging to that user from his/her first task set. Add a `tasks_from_first_task_set()` method on the the User model and return the query from inside of it. Then instead of using `tasks` as your source, use `tasks_from_first_task_set` instead.